# IHTMLElement event OnClick - how bind event to element in VBA (ACCESS)

Tags: vba, ms-access, web-scraping

Good day.
I very need help. I looked at many sources, but I have not yet found a specific solution to solve my problem.

I don’t understand the technical implementation of event binding to HTMLElement in the ACCESS VBA development environment.

Please explain to me in detail how to bind the event for the HTMLElement elements with the InternetExplorer object that I open and create in his document. 
In this example, this is an HTMLButtonElement.

The following is a working code in the module class:

```
Option Compare Database

Private WithEvents evtBUT As MSHTML.HTMLButtonElement
Private bd As HTMLBody

'event code
Private Function evtBUT_OnClick() As Boolean
bd.innerHTML = "!ТЕСТ!"
End Function

'begin the programm
Public Sub startProgramm()
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim nodeHTML As IHTMLDOMNode
Dim emtBUT As IHTMLButtonElement
Set doc = IeRun.Document
With doc
Set bd = .body
Set emtBUT = .createElement("button")
With emtBUT
.innerText = "click"
.OnClick = "evtBUT_OnClick" 'событие
With .Style
.Width = "100px"
.Height = "20px"
.TextAlign = "center"
End With
End With
Set nodeHTML = .getElementsByTagName("HTML")(, 0)
Set evtBUT = nodeHTML.insertBefore(emtBUT, nodeHTML.firstChild)

'evtBUT.Click 'testing event

End With
Set doc = Nothing
Set emtBUT = Nothing
Set nodeHTML = Nothing
End Sub

'IE object
Private Function IeRun() As InternetExplorer
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
With ie
.navigate "about:blank"
.Visible = True
Do
DoEvents
Loop While .ReadyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set IeRun = ie
End With
Set ie = Nothing
End Function
```

IE browser opens, element and buttons are successfully inserted.
Variables of the browser and element at the module level. Opening the browser, of course, the event does not occur, but in the console the code for the event works successfully.

Please tell me what should be the signature for the event code? Where the event code should be located and how to use it from the IE object?

I will be very appreciate.

**PS**

Not JS, only vba must be used. Console in the ACCESS environment for debugging. I mean, there are no errors in the code initialization - the object is available.

By the way, in vba, the OnClick event uses a function with a bool return. Sub method is a mistake.
But I still can’t associate an event with the element.

Comment: By console do you mean in the vbe? i think your onclick event is a vba sub not an htmlevent. You would want a js function you inject into the page. Someone please correct me if I am wrong,

Comment: Not JS, only vba must be used. Console in the ACCESS environment for debugging.

I added additions to my question - PLS see PS.

Comment: I meant execute the js via ie.document.parentWindow.execScript

Comment: friend, I don’t quite understand what you mean. But I this procedure calls the JS code. This is not what I need. The click method event works great. I need to catch the event from the IE object in VBA code. This is necessary for the exchange of data between the IE object and the access base.